# Dual nic Debian configuration

Tags: linux, networking, router, debian

If someone can just point me in the right direction, first time setting up dual nic. I'm stuck at this point. I have a Netgear Router to ISP, wired connection to Debian 9 PC (192.168.1.0). I would like to install 2nd NIC to connect a Raz Pi cluster. I'm looking into high availability server with failover, and this is the easiest(cheapest) route for me. I would prefer the cluster on a separate IP string(192.168.2.0 or 10.10.10.0). The cluster plugs into an 8 port switch, and the switch can plug into the 2nd nic, or another netgear router (attached to the 2nd nic), whichever would be easiest.

I've set Debian PC values in /etc/network/interfaces, but there is also a network gui setting. Is the gui overriding /etc/network/interfaces? Where should the settings be configured?

Comment: I, for one, fail to discern a real question here. Well, I perceive the first part of the text as describing some existing setup then ending up with a wish and no question, and the second part of the text actually asks a question bit it appears to be disconnected with the first one. So I'm confused as to what we're supposed to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Went with just keeping everything on the 192.168.1.0 string. I'll install a 2nd nic somewhere down the road.